# Adobe Flash Using DirectX

Tags: vb.net, flash, directx, adobe

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to render an Adobe Flash SWF file using DirectX. I know how to display an SWF using the Adobe ActiveX control but I want to render this to a DirectX surface without converting to an FLV file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For C++ try this: https://code.google.com/p/flash-to-directx/
It wraps ActiveX to device context then draws it to directx texture, has sample implementation fro DX9 and DX11.